# Size classes and view controller subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, size-classes

I have a view with two views, one installed for all size classes (View A) and the other installed for only Regular Regular (iPad only, View B). In `loadView` of my view controller, I want to go through all the subviews and set the background color.

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    changeBackgroundColor(view)
}

func changeBackgroundColor(view: UIView) {
     print(view)
     view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
     view.subviews.forEach { self.changeBackgroundColor($0) }
}
```

It's a contrived example but it illustrates a deeper issue with the iOS view hierarchy and view loading system. During `loadView` while running on an iPad, even though the trait collection returns as it should (with Regular Regular set), View B **is not present in the subview array**. The only subview that exists at that point in time is View A despite View B still showing up on screen at runtime (with an unchanged background color).

Fast-forward a bit to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and viola! **Both** views are now present as they should be in the subview array. I was able to verify that in load view the subview array count is 1 and in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` it's 2.

Does anyone know why iOS doesn't populate the subview array with Regular Regular views until right before a layout is performed? I can't find this behavior documented anywhere; I'm curious if others have run into a similar issue.